# Access Array in a model driven form

Tags: angular

In a modal driven form I have several properties. One property contains an Array. I want to display this array in a table:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="reproOrderForm">
 ...
 <div class="col-md-12" formArrayName="anyArray">
   <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
     <tr>
       <th>col1</th>
       <th>col2</th>
     </tr>
     <tr *ngFor="let elem of reproOrderForm.controls.anyArray.controls;let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
       <td>{{i+1}}</td>
       <td>{{elem.value.anyValue}}</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
 ...
</form>
```

in my component.ts I have defined this:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
   this.reproOrderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     ...
     anyArray: this.formBuilder.array([
       this.formBuilder.group({
         anyValue: []
       })
     ])
   });
}
```

My question is: Is it possible to access this array easier than I did in my HTML? And if so -> How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If template conciseness is your only concern, you could assign `myForm.controls.anyArray` (or even `myForm.controls.anyArray.controls`) to its own class property, e.g.:

```ts
export class MyComponent {
  reproOrderForm: FormGroup;
  formArray: FormArray;

  ngOnInit() {
    // Assign the array first
    this.formArray = this.formBuilder.array([
      this.formBuilder.group({
        anyValue: []
      })
    ]);
    // Then assign the form.
    this.reproOrderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       anyError: this.formArray
     });
  }
}
```

And then in your template:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let elem of formArray.controls;let i = index;">...</tr>
```